# Android - Display PDF from server

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Trying to display a PDF received from server but getting "Media not found error"

First I convert String to byte array:

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(stringData, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Then I write the byte[] to a file:

```
String path = getFilesDir() + "/myfile.pdf";     
File file = new File(path);

if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}

FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
stream.write(article.getFileDataBytes());
stream.close();
```

Then I try to display PDF:

```
Uri path2 = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path2, "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

But after calling startActivity I receive the "Media not found error"

I'm not sure what's wrong no exceptions are thrown when writing the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the file to internal storage. No third-party apps have access to your internal storage directly. Use `FileProvider` to make the PDF available to third-party apps.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) does pretty much what you need, except that I get the starting PDF from an asset.

Comment: What's best practice for cleaning up the files when no longer needed?

Comment: @MobileMon: Well, the problem is that you don't know when the other app is necessarily done with it. I'd put the file in `getCacheDir()` (my sample uses `getFilesDir()`) for starters, so in case of low disk space it's easy to get rid of. Then, I'd kick off a thread on app startup that got rid of cache files that are, say, older than 24 hours. You might need to be more aggressive than that if you have lots of files, or really big files, or something like that. "Best practice" is hard to define here.